# Extensionless URL trailing slash redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tested the code below on several Dreamhost domains, and it works, except on newer domains added circa 2012

```
RewriteEngine on

#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

#### example that works

[ryanve.com/resources/lame/](http://ryanve.com/resources/lame/) and [ryanve.com/resources/lame.php](http://ryanve.com/resources/lame.php) both redirect to [ryanve.com/resources/lame](http://ryanve.com/resources/lame) and the actual file that is served is lame.php

#### broken example

[airve.com/test/file](http://airve.com/test/file) properly serves file.php but the redirects [airve.com/test/file/](http://airve.com/test/file/) and [airve.com/test/file.php](http://airve.com/test/file.php) don't work. Try them and you'll see they seem to be spitting out the internal absolute path. The same thing occurred when I tried each of the redirects independently and when I tried the basic redirect below.

```
Redirect 301 /test/file/ /test/file
```

There is nothing else in .htaccess. Any idea on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to `$1` in both cases, and you don't have a RewriteBase directive to tell Apache where to root such a relative path.

Try adding a root slash before the $1 to anchor it to the root of your webserver, for instance:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```