# How-to? Vanity URL & ignore .PHP extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, vanity-url

I've got the following .htaccess working perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

This will allow me to write urls like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/peter  =>  http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?u=peter
```

But what if I want have an aditional rule to avoid writing the .php extension for existing files?

```
http://www.mysite.com/contact   (contact.php exists on file)
```

I tried adding this to my curr htaccess (but doesnt work):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

In other words, I would like to have vanity urls and ignore the .php extension in the same .htaccess.

---

SOLVED! 
Thanks to Ulrich Palha and Mario (didnt know about the ordering and the LAST [L] flag!

```
RewriteEngine on
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Does the rule for contact appear at the top of your .htaccess? If not, move it to the top, below RewriteEngine on

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4026021/911182

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8371815/1044340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of ordering. RewriteRules are applied in the order they are noted in the .htaccess
See [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Just add your new block as first rewrite statement, add a `[LAST]` flag, and it should work.

This rule works unconditionally (not guarded by any RewriteCond), so should always be the last of all RewriteRules:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ...
```

(And  all preceeding RewriteRules should preferrably carry a `[L]` flag. You have a bit of a workaround there.)

Answer (score 0):

For me this code work:

in "**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**" or "**httpd.conf**"

you must have (at least) these options in the default directory

```
...
    <Directory />
        ...
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        ...
    </Directory>
...
```

OR in the site specific site directory

```
...
    <Directory "/var/www/my-site">
        ...
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        ...
    </Directory>
...
```

and create or edit the "**.htacces**" in the directory of the site (for example "/var/www/my-site/.htaccess") and add this code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php htm html php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```