# Removing .php extension and "?id=xyz"

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing .php extension in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445077/removing-php-extension-in-urls)

I've changed the sub-directory of my `public_html` to act as the main-directory.
Currently, `mysite.com/alpha/index.php` redirects as `mysite.com`. This is working perfectly.

Similarly, I have another file `events.php`, i.e., `mysite.com/alpha/events.php?eventid=10` corresponds to `mysite.com/events.php?eventid=10`

But, I wanted to access the above path as `mysite.com/events/10/` instead of `mysite.com/events.php?eventid=10`. For this I again modified the file, but it fails to load the `dynamic URLs`.
For example, when I hover my mouse on links, it shows

```
`mysite.com/events/14` 
`mysite.com/events/15` 
`mysite.com/events/16` 
`mysite.com/events/17`
```

etc. [which is what I want]
But on clicking it [If I click on the link that showed `mysite.com/events/14` on hover], it opens a page `mydomain.com//alpha/events.php/14/14?eventid=` and page fetches nothing from the `sql` tables.

My .htaccess file:

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Copy and paste the following code into the .htaccess file
# in the public_html folder of your hosting account
# make the changes to the file according to the instructions.
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?eventid=$3
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/alpha/
# Don't change these line.'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /alpha/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ alpha/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @TomWalters: That question was also posted by me. That was to remove the `.php` extension and it did. This was to correct `sql` fetching as I was facing difficulty regarding it.

Comment: I don't think this question has any relation to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 7 of your apache config should be more like:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?eventid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The `sql` fields are shown now, though the URL in the address bar still : `http://www.tryst-iitd.com//13/events.php?eventid=25`

Comment: Apache doesn't change URL in your case, it just rewrites it. You do compose wrong URL in some other place.