# PHP serving pages for URLs with no extension

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have an OS X Snow Leopard Server that I use for development. I noticed that if I access `http://site.com/page` it serves `page.php` even though there is no `.htaccess` file that rewrites the URLs.

I would like to disable this option as it's not really something I want.

Thanks!

Later edit: The solution I noticed to work best is `Options -MultiViews` in `.htaccess`. Thanks to all!

Comment: Possibly MultiViews or mod_speling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide .php extension - htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)

Comment: You misunderstand, mario, he wanted to disable the rewriting, not enable it.

Comment: @red: I bet he still needs to know *what* to disable to do so. Disabling mod_rewrite is not overly helpful if that wasn't the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User mario answered my question, but since he did so in a comment I cannot accept that answer. I up-voted his comment, but I'm going to post the solution here, so anyone looking for something similar will find it easier:

```
options -multiviews
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the rewrite mod, you should disable it by removing rewrite.conf from enabled-modules under apache folder.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you'll want to disable the rewrite module. On a Mac you'll do this by commenting out the line `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` (put a semicolon on the beginning of the line) in the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Remember that you need root access to change this file, e.g. `sudo <favourite text editor> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Then restart apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache conf file and see if there are any rewrite settings there. Also check in any virtual host sections.

Answer (score 0):

surely in the apache server config files.

For development you can use also mamp for example :

[mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)