# How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want something to put in my `.htaccess` file that will hide the `.php` file extension for my php files, so going to www.example.com/dir/somepage would show them www.example.com/dir/somepage.php.

Is there any working solution for this? My site uses HTTPS, if that matters at all.

This is my .htaccess at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

It should be noted that this will also effect all HTTP requests, including POST, which  will subsequently effect all requests of this kind to fall under this redirection and may potentially cause such requests to stop working.

To resolve this, you can add an exception into the first `RewriteRule` to ignore POST requests so the rule is not allowed to them.

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo excluding POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: how can you exclude pages? This seems to be interfering with my login script so i would like to exclude that page from these rewrites

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. What i think is happening is when the page is being reloaded without the extension it is loosing the variables. is there a way to fix this? Its as if its logging in twice.... I think... once with the email and pass and then again without. so in all i cant login

Comment: I tired `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login.php)` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: After using this as my .htaccess, all my login will fail. It will keep direct me back to the login page. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: @Arios: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` condition in first redirect rule to avoid POST requests getting redirected.

Comment: @anubhava you saved my life

Comment: @anubhava 3 years later, you have also saved my life

Comment: @Skully: Thanks so much for your kind words and important edit in answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Remove php extension**

You can use the code in /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,L]
```

With the code above, you will be able to access /file.php as /file

**Remove html extension**

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [NC,L]
```

Note : 'RewriteEngine on' directive should be used once at top per htaccess, so if you want to combine these 2 rules just remove the  line from second rule. You can also remove any other extensions of your choice, just replace the .php with them on the code.

**Happy htaccessing!**

Answer (score 3):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f       # if the requested URL is not a file that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d       # and it isn't a directory that exists either
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php  -f  # but when you put ".php" on the end it is a file that exists
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.php [QSA]          # then serve that file (maintaining the query string)

</IfModule>
```

Oddly, this code gave me HTTP 500 errors when tried in XAMPP in Windows. Removing the comments fixed it. So did moving the comments so they were on their own lines, instead of on the same lines as instructions.

Comment: @Markum. I've since found that some implementations don't like comments on the same lines as code. Try removing the comments.

Comment: Had the same issue - Removing the comments solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]Try:
```

Reference:

[How to hide .php extension in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)