# redirect issue using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect using .htaccess `abc.com/test.php` to `abc.com/test`. but it will execute/display the content of test.php only.

how should I do this? any suggestions?

Comment: Do you not mean the other way around? As in if someone put in their browser http://abc.com/test you'd like to show them the test.php contents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of your current attempt, so we can see what you are actually trying to do? I think @RobForrest is right, but if we see the code we can tell for certain.

Comment: yes. I want the same thing. if user directly write `abc.com/test` then its okay. it should display `test.php` files contents only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
RewriteRule ^test$ test.php [L]
```

[update]

A complete redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I Would add the `QSA` flag as well as David has done in his answer, so potential query string will be appended too.

Comment: `abc.com/test` will display content of `abc.com/test.php` but `abc.com/test.php` should redirect to `abc.com/test`

Comment: @user985361 updated my answer to a better code

Comment: @sena it is working for all the files.. what if I want to implement it for specific files onle.. like test.php

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished using Rewrite Rules, rather than redirects. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test.php$ /test [L,QSA]
```