# Mod Rewrite Logic

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I never really have used mod re write and I am trying to understand the best way to implement it. removing the .php extension. i found this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

problem is that if the link is to domain.com/index.php it wont re write it domain.com/index

Also if i do the link domain.com/index the person can still add the .php and it still works fine.

I would like to know the proper way.. do i have to hard code the urls in the html or is there something that can do it automatically?

I dont want them to be able to add the .php to the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

Comment: You need to allow for both conditions, see the duplicate answer. If the point of hiding the ".php" extension is to obfuscate php, you might consider a 404 instead or route all extensions to the base route. If it's to prettify the urls, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions) should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional rule to remove `.php` . The rule you are using just allows you to access php files without their extension but doesn't remove the extension. To remove the `.php` you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1) redirect "/file.php" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R,NE]
#2) internally map "/file" back to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: starkeen how could i add this to the mix  http://localhost/site/profile/member.php?user=1308   to  http://localhost/site/profile/1308