# Removing the PHP file type extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using this in my top level .htaccess to remove the PHP file type extension on my *.php files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But I have discovered it also prevents my browser from calling the index.php page in my sub-directories. I need to include /index.php explicitly in the URL.

Is there a better way to remove the PHP file type extension on my *.php files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

Comment: How is this rule preventing you to use `domain.com/index.php` URL?

Comment: Sorry @anubhava I didd not explain well. It prevents the index page loading if browse to www.myurl.com/admin/. I have to browse to  www.myurl.com/admin/index.php to see the page.

Comment: Is `/admin/` a real directory? Does it have another .htaccess?

Comment: @Blueblazer172 resolved it

Comment: @PeteD how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

or try this one. This should also work in a sub-directory path:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

or in an `if clause`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```