# Cannot access .php on my server. Permission Denied

Tags: php

I just recently changed to Digital Ocean to have full Shell access and stuff to advance my knowledge of code. I made a script and removed .php from url's to make them look nicer in the url bar and as well i have had to create a ".php" file so i can re-route users to the login.php page. Since i have created the .php file i keep getting a 403 error. Access Denied. Its the same error that shows up when you place "Deny from all" in a .htaccess to block traffic from viewing a includes folder or etc. The error i get in the error log is:

> [Fri Jun 30 00:42:21.056280 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2808]
>   [client 76.111.178.215:50805] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: /var/www/affattraction.com/public_html/login/admin/.php

If anyone has encountered this or knows how i can give permission to access the page ".php" it will be greatly appreciated! This worked on my old cPanel.

Thanks!

Comment: I have added in .htaccess DirectoryIndex to index.php to see if that would help.

Comment: where is the filename `/var/www/affattraction.com/public_html/login/admin/.php`  `/.php` seems like that would be important to have...

Comment: what is the purpose of the `.php` page? In the case that someone requests `www.example.com/login/admin/` they would be served `www.example.com/login/admin/index.php` anyway. So using `index.php` to route seems more approprate.

Comment: May be from apache configuration, try to restart and re-config apache, set permission

Comment: I believe Linux treats files with no name ( files starting with . {periods} ) as special hidden files... Never tried using a php file with no name ... so with my limited knowledge of Linux I can say if that is bad or worse.  But it's probably not good convention.  unless that's just a typo..  think `.htaccess` special file.

Comment: It looks a htaccess file problem. look at this Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions

Comment: I still can't fix nothing. .htaccess has nothing blocked.