# Hide the php extension name from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the php or html's extension name from the url, but after going through lots of posts on the Internet and tried the methods, but my url does not work as I expected. What I want is xxx.com/xxx/home, instead of xxx.com/xxx/home.php

My system config

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS remote server on aws

Here are the steps I tried so far:

1. sudo a2enmod rewrite==>enable module rewrite
2. sudo vim apache2.conf==>config the apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. create a .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

4. put the .htaccess on my diectory (/var/www/html/.htaccess)

Is there any wrong step I made miss any configuration? Could someone help with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `mod_rewrite`, you can use [`MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: @anubhava, it looks hidding the extension name can work now on home page after adding the rule those rules in my apach2.conf. But, when I jump from home to login.php, the extension name appears again

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions/10031576#10031576

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the .htaccess to hide the php file extensions from the url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It is always useful to explain a bit how your code works when answering a question.

Comment: Should  the .htaccess file put in /var/www/html/? My home.php is in /var/www/html/blog/home.php. I tried add it but it does not work still

Comment: It should be in the root directory of the site where the domain is pointing to: ´/var/www/html/blog´

Comment: It's weird...still not work even I put it in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your `.htaccess` file

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```