# PHP links without extension

Tags: php, hyperlink

How I can change link from

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=123&g=123
```

to

```
www.example.com/index/id/123/g/123
```

?

Thank you :)

Edit:
Please don't tell me "use mod rewrite", tell me how to use it :D

Comment: `htaccess` `mod_rewrite` `rewriterule` might be helpful research tags for you

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138697/htaccess-rewrite-php-to-virtual-folder

Comment: `tell me how to use it` - how about you tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use **URL Rewriting**. See this article to accomplish that:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a mod rewrite (change `.htaccess` file)

Comment: yes but i don't know how :(