# .htaccess hide .php file extension, show /(slash) instead

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I want to change my *filename.php* to *filename/* through .htaccesss.

So, http://labs.ksj-oepites-zomergem.be/info.php#/deleiding 
should become http://labs.ksj-oepites-zomergem.be/info/#/deleiding

What I've got:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

### To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1\/ [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/$ $1.php [L]
```

This code will change *filename.php* to *filename* and NOT *filename/*

Using this code in my .htaccess, my site won't work as normal. 
When I call a php file using ajax in javascript.. I get an 'Unexpected EOF'

Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of:
[hide .php extension - htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)

The answer there was:
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

And that was a duplicate of:
[hide .php extension - htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)

Which had the answer:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

When hiding PHP, I tend to do the latter, with added rules for making .asp, .html, .cfm and .jsp also rewrite to the .php, so poking at the server shouldn't reveal the tech.  That said, I don't tend to hide it unless I'm asked to by a client, or I want to create shorter/prettier URLs.