# .htaccess file not working for extension hiding

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following code in the `.htaccess` file to hide the extension of the php file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ ([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

I placed this file in the `localhost/obis/`
But when I run the `index.php` file without the `.php` extension, the following error occurs.

`The requested URL /obis/index was not found on this server.`

Can anybody suggest what might be the error?

I took the code from this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6k_WvvpPpk

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide .php extension - htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)

Comment: I already checked and it isn't giving me a working solution.

Comment: you have a space in `^ ([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]`, it should be `^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]`

Comment: Nope, it's not working!

Comment: try this one `RewriteRule ^(.*)([^\.]+)$ $1$2.php [NC]`

Comment: @user1012181, Are you sure your Apache is configured correctly? You need to have `.htaccess` enabled for this directory, as well as [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) configured.

Comment: How to check if it is enabled?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo, it works when I put http://localhost/obis/sign-up/ (the / at the end. But I have to add ../ to the css links). But it doesn't work without adding '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these 2 rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index([/.]|$) /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: The requested URL /obis/sign-up was not found on this server.

Comment: is there any way to hide the 'index' from the url when we click on the logo to go back to the homepage?

Comment: Nope, its not removing `index`

Comment: It actually does redirect `site.com/index.php` to `site.com/` for which URL it didn't work?