# how to execute only specific files without extensions with PHP in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have specific files like `file.php` that I want to rename to `file` and then execute with PHP. Is it possible to do that with .htaccess?

For example, if I have files named `file`, `file2` and `file3` I want only `file` executed with PHP, not all files without extension.

Comment: you don't rename the files you use a rewrite command

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide .php extension in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/how-to-hide-php-extension-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I put in a few extra checks as well so it will ignore all files that start with a number.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file([0-9]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/file.php -f
RewriteRule ^file/?$ /file.php [L,QSA]
```