# How to Remove .PHP Correctly?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Ok, So iv'e decided to remove all .php extentions from the url, and for this iv'e used the simple method:

```
Options MultiViews+
```

However, My profile page now displays almost nothing, with a black background because of the URL. If I input:

```
profile.php?username=Joe.Bills
```

It works perfectly fine, If however, I use:

```
profile?username=Joe.Bills
```

It automatic changes the url and adds a `/` AFTER `profile` Example:

```
profile/?username=Joe.Bills
```

And thus, thinking its in a "separate directory" causes the error. How can i remove it from adding the additional `/` so it doesn't think its going to a separate directory

P.S. My link's are correct and currently is this:

```
<a href="profile?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>"><span class="bg">Profile</span></a>
```

Again, as I said, If I put

```
profile.php?username=Joe.Bills
```

It works completely fine, so I don't understand why the URL thinks its a directory when entered, So my question would be:

How can I remove .PHP extensions a different way to fix this, or is there a way I can fix this with what I currently have and how?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/how-to-hide-php-extension-in-htaccess

Comment: You can't just remove the .php extension, you need to do some research on url rewrite. Depending on whether you are using apache or nginx you will need to figure out how to do rewrites for that individual web server.

Comment: I did use this too: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]

Comment: But it gave me an internal error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following instead of **Options +Multiviews** :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 #remove trailing slashes
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

This will allow you to access .php files without extension/slash at the end.

Comment: i have tried this already which did give me an internal error, though i enabled rewrite_mod on my server, and it removed the .php, however when i go to profile, it still changes it with the `/` so this has something to do with my request maybe for the user? but I have no clue why this is happening. I have no links that have a `/` in so im unsure of where the error is coming from

Comment: @Joebills any other rules in the htaccess?

Comment: Okay, So i changed the request " $name = $_REQUEST['username']; " to "$name = $_REQUEST['user'];"  which then displayed as " profile?user=Joe.Bills " which worked fine, but i want it to be "username" not "user". Is there a way I could change it without the `/` happening again?

Comment: @JoeBills I am not good at php , not sure why the slash is appearing. Could you post your full htaccess in the question?

Comment: the only rule in my .htaccess is what you have posted in your answer.

Comment: @Joebill then the rule should work. Please check your php if you are still having the issue

Comment: Sorry I don't think you understand what I meant. Okay, So the rule works fine, it displays all pages without the .php extention. However, when I go to `http://localhost/profile?username=Joe.Bills` it changes it to `http://localhost/profile/?username=Joe.Bills` (adding a `/` after `profile`) BUT if I change the PHP Request code on my profile page, to "user", it would then be `http://localhost/profile?user=Joe.Bills` THEN it works fine. It just doesn't work if the request is set to "username" I'm not sure why

Comment: @Joebills I have adde a new rule to remove trailing slashes.

Comment: Ok that worked perfectly, Thank you for your help! I have no idea what or how .htaccess worked, but thank you!