# Url rewriting to hide .html and .php from all project files

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have few pages i my project they are:

```
index.php
aboutus.php
signup.html
login.html
```

I want to show in url without.php or .html 
i tried with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http://www.example.net/project name/index.php} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide .php extension in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/how-to-hide-php-extension-in-htaccess)

Comment: going good what is the problem

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya project pages are not loading.ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: `RewriteCond %{http://www.example.net/project name/index.php} !-f` possibly error in this line do i have to mention index or index.php or only project folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: what is in REQUEST_FILENAME , i want this to all files

Comment: not working @Abhishek Is there anything is missing i have included that file in project folder.

Comment: put this .htaccess file in directory on where you want to remove extension, comment out other rule if not important then try, even if not working try it in seperate project for testing.

Comment: Another thing project is in core php will it work on that or i need framework.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121908/discussion-between-abdul-waheed-and-abhishek-gurjar).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.ameryprod.com/index.html} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.ameryprod.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Finally i found this solution hope it works for you as well.